# MySQL replace foreign key in result table with data from FK table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this:

```
id (PK)   name    teacher (FK)    student (FK)
   1      Ron         3               6
```

Both teacher and student are in another table called `people`.

```
 people
 id (PK)   name   age
    3      Ali    42
    6      Jon    12
```

I would like to perform a query to obtain the following

```
name    teacher's name   student's name
 Ron         Ali              Jon
```

Is this possible? I know I can perform two separate joins, but then I am left with two rows and there is no indication of which name is the teacher and which is the student

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
select t.name, p1.name teacher_name, p2.name student_name 
       from t
left join people p1 on (t.teacher=p1.id)
left join people p2 on (t.student=p2.id)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name 'teacher name', c.name 'student name'
FROM mainTablle a 
LEFT JOIN people b ON a.teacher = b.id 
LEFT JOIN people c ON a.student = c.id 
WHERE a.id = 1;
```